# .NET: Combining two generic lists

Tags: .net, list

Let's say I have two generic lists of the same type. How do I combine them into one generic list of that type?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
List<Type> list1;
List<Type> list2;

List<Type> combined;
combined.AddRange(list1);
combined.AddRange(list2);
```

Comment: Is this the most efficient, or the most convenient way?

Comment: pstst .AddRange, Java is over there ->

Comment: @Ipthnc, I dont know a other way to do it, other than a `foreach()` combined with `List.Add()`.  But it sure is the most convenient way.

Comment: @gah. Heh im programming java right now. Annoying naming conventions.

Comment: Why not just do list1.AddRange(list2)?  It meets the requirements without having to create an additional list, and saves an entire add.

Comment: @Erich, that sure is a better way. My example just demonstrated the use.

Comment: Err, *no*, that's not necessarily a better way. You're assuming that it's OK to modify the first list (for that matter, why not do it to the second list instead?) when that's not made clear.

Comment: Indeed, that's the assumtion me and Erich made. I have to adjust my opinion on that one. Assuming it is okay to modify the first list, it is faster.

Answer (score 20):

You can simply add the items from one list to the other:

```
list1.AddRange(list2);
```

If you want to keep the lists and create a new one:

```
List<T> combined = new List<T>(list1);
combined.AddRange(list2);
```

Or using LINQ methods:

```
List<T> combined = list1.Concat(list2).ToList();
```

You can get a bit better performance by creating a list with the correct capacity before adding the items to it:

```
List<T> combined = new List<T>(list1.Count + list2.Count);
combined.AddRange(list1);
combined.AddRange(list2);
```

Comment: What is difference between join keyword and this way u declared?

Answer (score 9):

If you're using C# 3.0/.Net 3.5:

```
List<SomeType> list1;
List<SomeType> list2;

var list = list1.Concat(list2).ToList();
```

Comment: As a clarification, this requires .NET 3.5, not just C# 3.0 (extension methods are a part of C# 3.0, but the `System.Linq.Enumerable` class that defines them is part of .NET 3.5)

Comment: This can work on .NET 2.0 if you use VS2008 and LinqBridge ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using the .AddRange() method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx